# Get 3D coordinates of the both eyes in 3D Facemesh of ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to get real-world 3D coordinates of both eyes from the **3D Facemesh** of the **ARKit**.

So far, I have tried below code;

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor else { return }

    let geometry = virtualFaceNode.geometry as! ARSCNFaceGeometry

    let pointOfView = SCNNode()

    // Determine Adjusted Position for Right Eye
    let orientation : SCNQuaternion = node.orientation
    let orientationQuaternion : GLKQuaternion = GLKQuaternionMake(orientation.x, orientation.y, orientation.z, orientation.w)
    let eyePos : GLKVector3 = GLKVector3Make(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    let rotatedEyePos : GLKVector3 = GLKQuaternionRotateVector3(orientationQuaternion, eyePos)
    let rotatedEyePosSCNV : SCNVector3 = SCNVector3Make(rotatedEyePos.x, rotatedEyePos.y, rotatedEyePos.z)

    let mag : Float = 0.066 // This is the value for the distance between two pupils (in metres). The Interpupilary Distance (IPD).
    pointOfView.position.x += rotatedEyePosSCNV.x * mag
    pointOfView.position.y += rotatedEyePosSCNV.y * mag
    pointOfView.position.z += rotatedEyePosSCNV.z * mag

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.updateValue.text = "x= " + String(describing: pointOfView.position.x) + "y= " + String(describing: pointOfView.position.y) + "z= " + String(describing: pointOfView.position.z)

  }

    geometry.update(from: faceAnchor.geometry)
}
```

I am not sure this code works fine. If not than what is the other way to get the eyes coordinates? I want to calculate size, distance of eyes.

Appreciated your Help, Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Hi Ankit did you get any hint of how to procced. I want to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Any update on this? I am trying to achieve the same.